# Updated DNS zone but still seeing incorrect records after TTL expiry

Tags: domain-name-system, debian

I completely re-installed a `debian9-ispconfig3` server `ks392200.kimsufi.com` on its real IP `176.31.109.26` (That server was earlier installed on an IP FAILOVER `87.98.160.188` that I do not use anymore).

Here is the DNS zone for a vhost:

```
root@ns1:/etc/postfix# cat /etc/bind/pri.webologix.com
$TTL        600
@       IN      SOA     ks392200.kimsufi.com. unemail@noname.com. (
                        2018042411       ; serial, todays date + todays serial #
                        7200              ; refresh, seconds
                        540              ; retry, seconds
                        604800              ; expire, seconds
                        3600 )            ; minimum, seconds
;
mail           3600 A        176.31.109.26
www            3600 A        176.31.109.26
webologix.com. 3600 A        176.31.109.26
webologix.com. 3600      MX    10   mail.webologix.com.
webologix.com. 3600      NS        ks392200.kimsufi.com.
default._domainkey.webologix.com. 3600      TXT        "v=DKIM1; t=s; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArucYlp2rHXPGB3Xn0IjSIXSqixF9kkauZCqo30XIsGe5RShQnGDEUgfPZbHdw7O4wkfoobA6Lt3XBV6T9Zh8UGUNZcd//CgePZAWL4r6fkIvzlVHEhidDfQwaIAGMCZi/SI9TR+rlm2H7HJXlyeV1q5OfUnTO8NblFZ2QNuLhTxqusRQ3BVphkwBkXlyoUQgikj" "eNnStnwRNKsEqQ+Kmy4hYP3IrqV6odRAXcGGSqHNd82v/N+00gj2k1anr0MHUV0DVRHoQPcxVHB+x1/khoUsPRRdHCShNg5fsQMYbGryTTSRw3tJFKdCw7OaBS4W9mGRF+9FG2+wuaGKcdHscGQIDAQAB"
ownercheck 3600      TXT        "3374414b"
webologix.com. 3600      TXT        "v=spf1 mx a ~all"

$INCLUDE Kwebologix.com.+007+13847.key
$INCLUDE Kwebologix.com.+007+30810.key
```

Could someone tell me how dig can give the old IP where the server ***WAS*** installed ?

```
kmc@kmcs:~$ dig mail.webologix.com @ks392200.kimsufi.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> mail.webologix.com @ks392200.kimsufi.com
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.webologix.com.     3553    IN      A       87.98.160.188
...
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 10 22:51:21 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63
```

Please help a poor man very close to believe in Ghosts !

Comment: It's resolving to `176.31.109.26` here.

Comment: +1 from me for giving the real domain information.  This question would have been insoluble in the time available without it.

Comment: Re: your comments in the deleted answer... "I would delegate my DNS management but what about all the special stuffs like DKIM, SPF and all or different TXT fields ?" DKIM, SPF, and other text fields are no problem at all. Any decent DNS provider will support them just fine.

Answer (score 6):

When you do a `dig`, you're using your recursive DNS servers which will be obeying TTL caches. Depending on the TTL (Time To Live) of the DNS record, it may return a stale (out of date) record. There's not much you can do about this until the TTL expires and the caches fetch fresh records. That's what most people's issues with incorrect DNS records are.

However, this is not your only issue. At your registrar you have two NS registered for your domain:

- `ns.kimsufi.com` (213.186.33.199)
- `ks392200.kimsufi.com` (176.31.109.26)

When I `dig` directly at those servers I get different responses:

```
dig mail.webologix.com @176.31.109.26

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> mail.webologix.com @176.31.109.26
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51233
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mail.webologix.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.webologix.com.     3600    IN      A       176.31.109.26
```

and

```
dig mail.webologix.com @213.186.33.199

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> mail.webologix.com @213.186.33.199
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19290
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mail.webologix.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.webologix.com.     3600    IN      A       87.98.160.188
```

Firstly: you have two NS returning different data. One is up to date, and one is not. Get them both up to date.

Secondly: Honestly there is little to no reason to ever run your own DNS these days, except as a learning experiement in a non production environment. I see you plan on pulling web, mail and DNS into a single box. This means when that box goes down you lose *everything*, you can't even route your mail somewhere else. I strongly suggest using a 3rd party (CloudFlare, Route 53, Google DNS, Azure DNS) for your DNS. 3rd party DNS is very very cheap, and in the case of CloudFlare, free.

Comment: +1 from me, except for the bit about not running your own DNS.  I can think of a lot of reasons to run your own DNS, and they convince me enough to do my own.  I would agree, however, that there is never a good reason to do *anything* for yourself that you're not willing to learn enough about in order to do it properly.  All such tasks should be contracted out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a flag 'Protection against transfers' in my registrar (OVH) domain definition was preventing the secondary DNS update or was it just propagation delay ?
Don't now but I removed the flag and propagation started to work.
Now my DNS seems to be fine.